# Move Woocommerce Single Products Title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was trying to move the **product title** at Woocommerce single product page to different location. The accepted location is just under `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"` and i was trying to remove first the title from current location which is `remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 50);` but not removed the title from current location.

Another problem is I can't add product title to new location which I have used `do_action( 'woocommerce_moved_product_title_position' );` and then `add_action('woocommerce_moved_product_title_position', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 60);`

I am using Woocommerce 2.4.13 and WordPress 4.4.1

Please help me to solve this. It'll be great for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weirdly, you must call `remove_action` from inside a function.

```
function so_34845641_move_title(){
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 50); 
    add_action('woocommerce_moved_product_title_position', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 60);
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'so_34845641_move_title' );
```

Just a suggestion that there are *probably* enough hooks without needing to add a custom `do_action()` in the templates.

Comment: Thanks @helgatheviking

Comment: @helgatheviking this worked great for me, thank you! How can I add a custom wrapper div (example: <div class="wrapper"> .. </div>) outside the title? Maybe by modifying the woocommerce/single-product/title.php template itself? Thank you again for the great answer!

Comment: Try adding your markup in 2 more `add_action()` statements. 1 before and 1 after (modify the priority number to adjust when it is fired... one a low priority and one a high priority).

Answer (score -1):

Run the remove_action inside a function doesn't change anything , but change the priority work for me.

I give you an example:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 15 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 10 );
```

Pay attention and try with differents priorities.